# Create a war with boot-clj

Tags: clojure, war, boot-clj

I want to create a war that I can deploy with tomcat. Using `lein uberwar` did the job just fine, however doing the same with boot doesn't seem to work. I can build a jar and run it, but the war fails with

> Dec 09, 2015 12:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/sites/geeknow.guru/DEBUG##0.1.7/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar)
>   - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

I'm using the following build.boot

```
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src/clj"}
 :resource-paths #{"resources" "src/clj"}
 :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [clj-time "0.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.7"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1202-jdbc41"]
                 [yesql "0.5.1"]
                 [migratus "0.8.6"]
                 [markdown-clj "0.9.67"]
                 [jarohen/nomad "0.7.2"]
                 [com.draines/postal "1.11.3"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-devel "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5"] 
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.4.0"]
                 [ring-refresh "0.1.1"]
                 [ring-logger-timbre "0.7.5"]
                 [com.taoensso/timbre "4.1.4"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                 [garden "1.3.0"]
                 [danlentz/clj-uuid "0.1.6"]
                 [speclj "3.3.1" :scope "test"]
                 [pandeiro/boot-http "0.7.1-SNAPSHOT"]])

(require '[pandeiro.boot-http :as http])
(require '[ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]])
(require '[ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty])
(require '[ring.middleware.refresh :refer [wrap-refresh]])
(require '[blog.handler])

;;;;taken from boot-http.util
(defn resolve-sym [sym]
  (require (symbol (namespace sym)) :reload)
  (resolve sym))

(deftask ring-server
  []
  (comp (jetty/run-jetty (wrap-refresh (wrap-reload (resolve-sym 'blog.handler/app))) {:port 3000}) (wait)))

(deftask uberwar
  []
  (comp (aot) (pom) (web) (uber) (war)))

(deftask uberjar
  []
  (comp (aot) (pom) (uber) (jar)))

(task-options!
 pom {:project 'geeknow
      :version "0.1.7"}
 ;uber {:as-jars true}
 aot {:all true}
 jar {:main 'blog.core
      :manifest {"Description" "blog"}}
 web {:serve 'blog.handler/app}
 war {:main 'blog.core
      :manifest {"Description" "blog"}}
 repl {:init-ns 'blog.core})
```

Comment: you are building with a jdk<8 and one library there is built using jdk8

Comment: I know. That's why I tried building the clojure-adapter-servlet myself, but it didn't help. I used the following command to build and install it if that helps `boot -s src -d tailrecursion/clojure-adapter-servlet:0.2.1 -- pom -p clojure-adapter-servlet -v 0.2.1 -- jar -- install`

Comment: I updated Java on the server. Now I get a new error. I updated the question accordingly

Comment: You included the jetty adapter in your dependencies, which will collide with your deployment to Tomcat. Not sure this is the cause of the error message though.

Comment: I need the jetty adapter to run a local server. I tried removing it to build the war, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat is complaining because one of the jars included in your war file contains a class that only the container environment can provide.  The offending jar in the war is `WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar`.

By default, the `uber` task adds all dependencies, direct and transitive, to the war at `WEB-INF/lib` when `--as-jars` is set to true.  `--as-jars` is the preferred way of bundling dependencies for deployment to servlet containers.

The problem appears to be that one of your direct dependencies is bringing in `javax.servlet-api` and `uber` is packaging it, causing the Tomcat problem.

First we need to figure out which dependency is bringing in `javax.servlet-api`.  `boot show` contains many options for diagnosing dependency problems like this.  You can learn about them all with `boot show -h`.  The one we want now is `boot show -d`, which prints the dependency tree.

Here is the fragment of relevant output:

```
[ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.4.0"]
├── [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server "9.2.10.v20150310"]
│   ├── [javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api "3.1.0"]
│   ├── [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http "9.2.10.v20150310"]
│   │   └── [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util "9.2.10.v20150310"]
│   └── [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io "9.2.10.v20150310"]
└── [ring/ring-servlet "1.4.0"]
```

From this output, we know that our dependency on `ring/ring-jetty-adapter` is what's causing `javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api` to be brought in.

Because this dependency is necessary for local development we don't want to omit it entirely.  Instead, we can add the dependency with `"test"` scope:

```
[ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.4.0" :scope "test"]
```

Scopes are a [Maven concept](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) for limiting the transitivity of dependencies in scenarios such as these.  Boot uses Maven for its underlying dependency resolution machinery.  `uber` is sensitive to Maven scopes, and can be configured to include or exclude various scopes depending on your needs.  See `boot uber -h` for more information.

By default, the `uber` task won't package dependencies in `"test"` scope.  By marking `ring/ring-jetty-adapter` this way, we've excluded it from our uber war.

The `"test"` scope is also useful for dependencies you might use in tests (of course!), or for deployment, or for other tasks during which you need a dependency but don't want to distribute it with your artifact, whether it's a library jar or an uberwar web app.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It really helped my to understand the problem. Unfortunately, `ring-defaults` also brings in `javax.servlet/servlet-api`. I think need `ring-defaults` for `ring.middleware.defaults` which I use in my project. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Held you can exclude `servlet-api` from `ring-defaults` with `[ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5" :exclusions [javax.servlet/servlet-api]]`.  Then, separately, bring in `servlet-api` *only in development* with `[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5" :scope "test"]`.

Comment: Disregard what I said about bringing in the servlet-api again, it's already provided locally by ring-jetty-adapter.

Comment: I tried it, but I got another error. However, since I've given up on my web project and this helped me get rid of one error and contains some useful information I'll mark it as complete. Thanks again.